# Codeception $I->click(<button text>) results in: [ErrorException] Undefined property: DOMDocument::$tagName

Tags: domdocument, codeception

I am using Codeception 2.2.6 to test a Laravel app.  I have a simple test that opens a page with a form, fills some fields, and then clicks a button.  When I run the test it works fine until the click step and then it fails with the following error:

```
[ErrorException] Undefined property: DOMDocument::$tagName
```

The stack trace shows that the error is raised from the `clickButton` method in `Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser.php`:

```
/**
 * Clicks the link or submits the form when the button is clicked
 * @param \DOMNode $node
 * @return boolean clicked something
 */
private function clickButton(\DOMNode $node)
{
    $formParams = [];
    $buttonName = (string)$node->getAttribute('name');
    $buttonValue = $node->getAttribute('value');

    if ($buttonName !== '' && $buttonValue !== null) {
        $formParams = [$buttonName => $buttonValue];
    }

    while ($node->parentNode !== null) {
        $node = $node->parentNode;
        if ($node->tagName === 'a') {
            $this->openHrefFromDomNode($node);
            return true;
        } elseif ($node->tagName === 'form') {
            $this->proceedSubmitForm(
                new Crawler($node),
                $formParams
            );
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have other similar tests that use click on different pages with no problems.  Could someone help me figure out what is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the page that the test was running on was not valid HTML.  I had a  tag that was not closed properly.  This was causing Codeception's DOM crawler to fail.

Edit (re my note below):

The breaking HTML had this essential structure:

```
    <div>  <!-- this should be inside the form -->
        <form> <!-- this should be outside the div -->
    </div>
    <button>The Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you raise an issue at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues and provide a sample of HTML which caused that error? Thanks

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3783 .  It turns out that it wasn't so much an improperly closed tag as it was an improperly opened form tag.  I've edited my answer above to be more clear.